# Use part of filename to add as a field/column

Tags: bash, for-loop, hadoop, filenames, hdfs

I get 5 files everyday (via wget) saved to /tmp to be loaded to hdfs in a bash script.

donaldDuck-2013-07-20.zip 
mickeyMouse-2013-07-20.zip 
goofyGoof-2013-07-20.zip 
plutoStar-2013-07-20.zip 
bigBadWolf-2013-07-20.zip

The date part of the filename is dynamic.

How do I then tell hadoop to load each of the 5 files in? I heard something about a loop.

```
for file in /tmp/*; do
echo "Running ${file##*/} ...."
done
```

Do I replace the echo line with the "hadoop fs -put..." statement? How will it look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

when=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d") #output like 2013-07-23
names=(donaldDuck mickeyMouse goofyGoof plutoStar bigBadWolf)

for file in "${names[@]}"
do
        ls -l $file-$when.zip #output like donaldDuck-2013-07-23.zip
done
```

#### Explanation

The names are stored in an array `$names`. Hence, we can loop through it with `for file in "${names[@]}"`. In parallel, we have the date stored in `$when`, so that the format is matched with `$file-$when.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
hdfsdir=/path/to/hdfs/output/dir
datethru=`date "+%Y-%m-%d" --date="3 days ago"` # replace by how many days ago you want
for i in `ls /tmp/*-$datethru.zip`; do
    hadoop fs -put $i $hdfsdir
done
```

This will essentially grab all the files in your directory that contain a specific date and end in .zip, and upload each of these files to a specific directory in hdfs.

Comment: the `for i in /tmp/*-$datethru.zip` - is safer and cleaner as parsing output from ls.